# Does grunt-contrib-less support --source-map-map-inline?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

Title says it all. Is this Less option:

http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-source-map-map-inline

Available via grunt-contrib-less, or some other plugin? I'm not hopeful since it does not seem be mentioned anywhere in the grunt-contrib-less docs.

To be clear, I don't want grunt to output a separate map file, I'd like the mapping information to appear inline, in the primary output CSS file.

Comment: [gulp-less](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less) and [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps) support it as the default.

Answer (score 0):

It sure does, here's a stripped down config of what I use:

```
    less: {
        options: {
            sourceMap:true,
            outputSourceFiles: true
        },
        lessFiles: {
            src: [
                '*.less'
            ],
            ext: '.css',
            cleancss:true
        }
    },
```

Comment: Should also be covered in the docs: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less