# Less SourceMap absolute file paths using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, less, source-maps, grunt-contrib-less

I have a file structure that looks like this (simplified for brevity):

```
/less/
     /styles.less
/public/
       /css/
           /styles.css
           /styles.css.map
/gruntfile.js
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
less: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/css/styles.css.map',
        sourceMapURL: 'less/styles.less'
    }
    files: {
        'public/css/styles.css': 'less/styles.less'
    }
}
```

In the html file: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`

Now the issue is that in dev tools, `styles.less` points to `/css/less/styles.less`. That's clearly not right, as it should be `/less/styles.less`. But I can seem to get it to point to the project root.

I've tried `sourceMapBasepath` and `sourceMapRootpath` options without any luck.

Thoughts?

Another thing is in my css file (`/css/styles.css`), I get this:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjp... */
```

Why is it a base64 output? I thought it should just point to the `styles.css.map` file.

Answer (score 1):

with grunt-contribe-less 1.0.0

the following task

```
less: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapRootpath: '/'

    },
    files: {'css/t.css' : 'less/t.less'}
  }
```

}

generate a `css/t.css`, and a `css/t.css.map`. The last file will be generated automatically without need to set sourceMapFilename.

The above does not generate a inline source map (with base64 output).

`css/t.css` ends with:

/*# sourceMappingURL=css/t.css.map */

Possible it depends of your version of grunt-contrib-less, see also [Does grunt-contrib-less support --source-map-map-inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543823/does-grunt-contrib-less-support-source-map-map-inlin) (which describes inline source maps as you describe)

<strike>read: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less</strike>

set `sourceMapBasepath` to `/`.

> Why is it a base64 output? I thought it should just point to the
>   styles.css.map file.

--

> sourceMapFilename
>
> Type: String Default: none
>
> Write the source map to a separate file with the given filename.

Comment: I have `sourceMapBasepath: '/'`. No luck. And shouldn't `sourceMapFilename: 'public/css/styles.css.map'` take care of the base64 issue?

Comment: well, yes i did answer your question to quick. set `sourceMapRootpath: '/'` instead of `sourceMapBasepath`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it seems to point the less file to the right path (`/less/styles.less`). But chrome throws a 404 on the file and I still get base64 sourceMappingUrl.

Comment: I'm on grunt-contrib-less 1.0.0 and tried removing sourceMapFilename but still see the base64 issue either way.

Comment: i only find a base64 data uri inline when the`sourceMapFileInline` had been set